# How to set variable email address in php mail function

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send an email address from my index.php to form.php file. In form.php I get the email address correctly or prints correctly. But when i am trying to sending an email to that particular email address using php mail() function. It's not working. Can anyone suggest me how to fix this ?

**index.php**

```
 <form method="POST" action="Form.php">
 <input type="email"  name="email" placeholder="Email" >
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit-form" class="hidden" style="display:none">
 </form>
```

**Form.php**

```
<p>To :'.$_POST["email"].'</p> // showing email address

<?php
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $to = $_POST["email"];     // does not sending email
    $subject = 'my subject';
    $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
    $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
    $headers[] = 'From: my@email.com';
    mail($to, $subject, $hippo , implode("\r\n", $headers));
}
?>  
<div id="submitBtn">
<label for="submit-form" class="submitBtn">Submit</label>
</div>
```

Comment: where is the submit button? `<label>` is not a button

Comment: I put the submit button outside the form and using that <label> as a submit button.

Comment: Are you running this on localhost?

Comment: any reason for doing this? & yeah good point @siraj

Comment: no i am not running it in localhost.

Comment: why you are not putting your submit button inside the form?

Comment: Edited and that's how i am using submit button. and i don't want to show the submit button in the form so i am using it this way. This is HTML5 attribute.

Comment: why is this question still open? seems like answers given below have solved this one, yes/no?

Comment: *"no i am not running it in localhost."* - then where are you running this from? a hosted site or your own computer?

Comment: `$hippo` where is that defined?

Comment: No, This didn't solve my question.

Comment: i've declared my whole html document in $hippo as a message.

Comment: I've solved my question some other way though. but not with the stackoverflow's answers.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a submit button in your form and you ask if submit was in form 
the correct way is

```
<form method="POST" action="Form.php">
  <input type="email"  name="email" placeholder="Email" >
  <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

And now the code of **Form.php** will work

Answer (score 0):

Check your headers and `mail()` function, see if it is actually redirecting you to the form page or not,

try the code below :

**index**

```
<form method="POST" action="Form.php">
<input type="email"  name="email" placeholder="Email">
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit-form">
</form>
```

**Form**

```
$to      = $_POST['email'];
$subject = "My Subject" ;
$message = "Got the mail";
$header = "From: my@email.com\r\n"; 
$header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$header.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; 
$header.= "X-Priority: 1\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
```